# 24V to optocoupler (voltage drop of 22.8V)

Tags: voltage, opto-isolator, zener, 24v

I have to detect a signal of 24V. The length of the signal is 1 second. So I use an optocoupler. The led inside the optocoupler must receive 1.2V.

First I use a resistor (4k7) but the resistor heat too much for the environment of my prototype (50 degrees).

I made some research and I thought use a 2V zener diode like in this scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHYc83.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is that a good solution? Will it heat a lot?

**EDIT:**

I want to add that this circuit will be part of a PCB. So can I use cms resistor and diode?

**EDIT 2:**

As asked in the comments and answer, the optocoupler LED need 20 mA to work

Comment: It could be useful if you show the optocoupler load with its current requirement. There are some fairly high CTR optocouplers that can operate off of currents much lower than 20mA if they do not have to drive too much current. For example [FOD817D3S](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FO/FOD817D.pdf).

Comment: Also, please include the part number for the optocoupler you are using.

Comment: Also zener will dissipate heat. No need to complicate things, use 1.1kohm series resistor with adequate power raing.

Comment: Use two or more resistors in series or parallel to spread the heat over several components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IRLED in your opto drops 1.2V with 20mA through it, then the value of the ballast resistance must be:

$$R = \frac {V_{IN} - V_{LED}}{I_{LED}} = \frac{22.8V}{0.02A} = 1140\text{ ohms} $$

1100 ohms is a standard E24 value, it'll allow

$$I = \frac {V_{IN} - V_{LED}}{R} = \frac{22.8V}{1100\Omega} \approx 21 \text{ milliamperes}$$

through the LED, and it'll dissipate

$$ P = I^2R = 0.00044\times 1100\Omega \approx 0.5\text{ watt} $$

I'd use a 1 watt resistor, and if you want to go thru-hole, [**here's a link**](http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDB0000/AOA0000C249.pdf).

If you want to go surface mount,[**here's a link**](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDA0000/AOA0000C84.pdf) to something that should work in your ambient temp.

Also, I've excerpted the derating curve for the surface mount resistors and it looks like at about 110C or so the 1 watt unit can dissipate half a watt or so.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your led is taking 1,2 V then you have to lose 22,8 V over a resistor. The value of the resistor depends on the current required by the led inside the opto coupler. ( look in the specsheet). Let us take 20 mA. Then the series resistor needed would be 1,14 Kohm. Take three resistors of 3,3 kOhm and connect them in parallel and you end up with 1,1 KOhm.The led will now receive 20,72 mA. That is ok. The total dissipation would be 0,472 Watt over three resistors. So if you take three resistors of 0,25 Watt. Select a resistor that is easy capable of handling the energy. If the resistor is to small it will heat up to much. The problem you had must have come from a to small resistor (not in value but in Watts) not from the total amount of energy dissipated.

Following the calculation you can try to reduce the current flowing into the led and recalculate the resistor value. Make sure the resistors single, in series or parallel are able to handle the dissipation.

Comment: Okay but use a zener diode is not too a good solution? The required current into the optocoler is 20 mA. I made a test with a 10k resistor and the resistor is going up to 40 degres.

Comment: I changed the answer so it matches your 20 mA. If your resistor is getting to hot then the size ( not the value) forms the problem. If you need 20 mA then a 10k resistor should not work. Pls look again.

Comment: Sorry @Majonsi, it will sound an off-topic but I'm just wondering why the current need for optocoupler LED is 20mA. You said that the goal is detection. Could you please share the other (photo-transistor) side of the circuit? I'm raising this question, because most recent optocouplers have a CTR (Current transfer ratio) of at least %100 and maybe the other side does not need that level of current, so we can make the detection block "cheaper" in order to resolve that heat issue.

Answer (score 1):

A 4.7k resistor there will put about 5mA into your opto.

If you change that to 10k, it will put about 2.5mA into the opto, and get half as hot as the 4.7k choice.

If 2.5mA is enough for your application, then just use 10k instead. D1 *increases* the heating in R1 for any given opto current.

As the fundamental problem is having enough current at the opto to make it work, and low enough heating in the dropper resistor, the only thing you can do, without doing something very complicated, is to a) choose the largest value resistor possible that still gives you enough opto current, and then b) if that resistor gets too hot, split it physically into several resistors in series.

Comment: I made a test with a 10k resistor and without a diode but the resistor heat always a lot (40 degres after measurment). The optocopler need 20 mA. So ou said that use a zener diode will not reduice the heat?

Comment: If you need 20 mA then a resistor of 10k does not work. With 10k you would have less 3 mA and that is not enough following your own specs

Comment: I doubt you *need* 20mA, more likely 20mA is the maximum, or the rated current at which specs are quoted. Try it will less diode current, and a lower current load on the output side.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use a zener + resistor or a resistor or a linear constant-current circuit, the total heating will be exactly the same for the same LED current.

To reduce the power dissipation, you can specify a better optocoupler that has higher current transfer ratio. Don't forget to account for temperature and aging, so you might use 50-100% more current than the minimum guaranteed operating current at 25°C.

It's also possible to use a switching supply to reduce the power dissipation, but that would be a bit silly.

---

If you pick an optocoupler with 100% CTR at 1mA and run it at 2mA with, say, 100uA collector current on the transistor you'll have rise and fall times still sub-millisecond and you can use a 10K or 11K resistor, dissipating only 50mW. Using less conservative design you could easily halve that.

Incidentally, 4.7K only dissipates 112mW or so, which should be tolerable in a 50°C environment using a 1206 resistor. Read the datasheet, but typically a standard rated 1206 will dissipate 250mW maximum at 70°C, with the resistor itself running at 155°C under those conditions. At half the maximum power it should be reasonably reliable. There are high power versions that will dissipate 1/3-W or more, but I would tend to split it into two standard equal value resistors rather than using a special part.

---

Be sure to allow adequate margin for the opto- the high temperatures will cause more trouble there than for a simple passive part like a resistor which is operated well within ratings.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good solution.  The zener clamp in your circuit does nothing useful.  Overall, it will cause *more* dissipation than just a resistor in series with the LED.

You said the LED drops 1.2 V when on, but not what current you want to run it at.  Let's say 1 mA to pick something.  Even with a crappy CTR (current transfer ratio), you still have plenty of current capability on the output to drive something like a 10 kΩ pullup low.

With 24 V applied and the LED dropping 1.2 V, something else needs to drop the remaining 22.8 V.  We also know the current needs to be about 1 mA.  Given a voltage and a desired current, we can compute the resistance that would allow that current to flow:  (22.8 V)/(1 mA) = 22.8 kΩ.  The common value of 20 kΩ will work fine.

Now that we've picked a value, let's see what the other parameters come out to.  (22.8 V)/(20 kΩ) = 1.14 mA, which is plenty to drive the LED as discussed before.  The power dissipated by the resistor is (22.8 V)<sup>2</sup>/(20 kΩ) = 26 mW.  That's so little that you'll have a hard time noticing a temperature rise in a 0805 package with your finger, and is certainly well within specs for even a small resistor.

Here is the overall circuit I'm talking about:

[image]

This particular opto-coupler has a CTR of 3.  That means that with 1.14 mA in, it can support up to 3.4 mA on the output.  Even with 5 V at the other end of a pullup, this circuit only requires 500 µA output capability.  You can work this backwards and see how low a pullup can be supported:  (5 V)/(3.4 mA) = 1.5 kΩ.  A 2 kΩ pullup, for example, would be well within spec here.

Given that you are trying to detect a event lasting 1 second, a larger pullup like 10 kΩ or whatever is built into your microcontroller should do fine.  If the timing of the edges matter to less than 20 µs, then you need to use a different opto-coupler, which will probably have a lower CTR.